# GreenDroid ActionBar methode name conflicts

Tags: android, greendroid

When I install the GreenDroid library eclipse gives me two errors, one in greendroid.app.GDActivity and one in greendroid.app.GDTabActivity

in greendroid.app.GDActivity:

```
    public ActionBar getActionBar() {
    ensureLayout();
    return mActionBarHost.getActionBar();
}
//The return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar()
```

in greendroid.app.GDTabActivity:

```
  public ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return mActionBarHost.getActionBar();
}    
 //The return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar()
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution that i found for this problem was to use the Android 2.2 APIs (API Level: 8) for the project.